# LastPage Package, don't count included pdfs in appendix

Tags: fancyhdr, lastpage

I use the `LastPage` package and the `fancyhdr` package to create a footer that lookes like

```
%Footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize{\doctype} {\docname}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{\docnumber} Rev.{\docversion}}
```

That works fine so far, but my document has a lot of included PDFs in the appendix which anyway will not have the footer so I'd like my `LastPage` reference to be the page where I start my appendix.

```
\section{Addendum} \label{sec:addendum}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Drawing; A drawing
    \item Manual; A Manual
    \item Drawing; Another drawing
\end{enumerate}
%% <-- Here should my LastPage reference go


\includepdf[pages={-},angle=90]{./content/addendum/1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={-}]{./content/addendum/2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={-}]{./content/addendum/3.pdf}
```

How would I achieve that?

Comment: You could put a `\label{mypage}` where you want and say `\pageref{mypage}` when you need it.

Comment: Hmm, okay I'll do it this way then, thanks. Just thought there might be a way that doesn't rely on an actual label in the document (e.g. in case someone deletes the whole appendix section)